# Accessing Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code :

```
$('button#monbtn').click(function() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var msg = $('#msg').val();

  var url = "{{ path('ajax_subcategories', {'username': username,'msg':msg})|escape('js') }}";
}
```

I get the username and msg from inputs, and i want to add them to the url, but i get an error saying that variable username doesn't exist.

Comment: concat in string?

Comment: Which variable is it saying doesn't exist?  The `url` variable won't exist outside that function.  Look into scoping.  As for what's being assigned to `url`, you're just writing strings out.  You need to escape the string, concat the variable, then continue with the string.

Comment: Consider using template strings. `\`Hello ${username}\``

Answer (score 1):

You're not writing the username variable, you're literally writing the word `username` into the string. Hence the template parser (I guess) says that itself does not know this var.

In JS, you have to print vars like this:

```
var url = "{{ path('ajax_subcategories', {'username': "+username+",'msg':"+msg+"})|escape('js') }}";
```

Comment: Since he never attempts to use the variable, this error wouldn't be coming from here..

It's mostly likely coming from somewhere not shown and is most likely a scope issue

Comment: I think the problem is in concatenating the {{ with the rest of the string, the parser doesn't consider "{{" as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables will not be recognized as strings. Concatenate your variables into the final string url.

```
$('button#monbtn').click(function() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var msg = $('#msg').val();

  var url = "{{ path('ajax_subcategories', {'username': " + username + ",'msg':" + msg + "})|escape('js') }}";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i still get the string not the value : for example if the username value is john, i still get it as +username+ in the database

Comment: I can't really understand why that would be. Try to console.log the username value right after it is created. What do you get then?